Packer not running any shell scripts
I have a provisioner to run a shell script, as per all the docs I found on the line, but nothing seems to actually run anything, it just sits and exists after a minute or two.
 "provisioners": [
    {
      "execute_command": "chmod +x sudo bash -c -E '{{ .Vars }} {{ .Path }}'",
      "scripts": [
        "scripts/harden-remove-services.sh"
      ],
      "type": "shell"
    }
  ]

scripts/harden-remove-services.sh

#!/bin/sh -x
apt purge cups  isc-dhcp-server slapd nfs-kernel-server bind9 vsftpd apache2 dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d samba squid snmp nis rsync rsh-client talk telnet ldap-utils rpcbind

As an actual output - this is all I get.
==> azure-arm: Provisioning with shell script: scripts/harden-remove-services.sh
==> azure-arm: Provisioning step had errors: Running the cleanup provisioner, if present...


It's me - I was removing the root account before anything happened so it binned the whole process
